# prevent LHS from evaluating in Set

Tags: functions, function-construction

Reading Ted Ersek's trickpage I stumbled upon the following problem:

http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_P-Z_19.html (last example)

```
Clear[g,h];
g = h;
h[2] = 9;
{g[2], h[2]}
(* {9,9} *)
```

my question: is it possible to prevent `g[2]` to evaluate to a different value rather than `h[2]` and eventually `9`. Furthermore can we assign `g[2]` different values?

My own tries led me to come up with the use of `TagSet`:

```
g/: HoldForm[g[2]] = 0;

SetAttributes[wrapper,HoldAll];
wrapper[x_]:= HoldForm@x;
```

Now with these definitions i can in a round-about way display different value for `wrapper[g[2]]`

```
{wrapper[g[2]], g[2]}
(* {0,9} *)
```

To change value I still need to use `TagSet` as shown below:

```
g/: HoldForm[g[2]] = 1;
{wrapper[g[2]], g[2]}
(* {1,9} *)
```

Reiterating, this is indeed a circular way to overcome the problem. Is there a better way to prevent `g[2]` to evaluate to `h[2]`?

Comment: Please do include the appropriate link to Ted's page, for reference.

Comment: @J.M. thanks will do !

Comment: @CarlWoll thanks i think i understood what you mean